# Android recyclerview unable to drag bottomsheet

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I am building an Android app and instead of using BottomSheet. I am applying BottomSheet behavior to the layout. The parent xml file has a coordinator layout in which I include this layout. I am unable to drag the bottomsheet from the recycler view, but I can do so from the collapsible toolbar. Any idea how I can get this working. Following is the code from my xml file. Thanks in advance. The material design api version and recyclerview api version is 1.0.0

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarStyle"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                            style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/image_button"
                                android:layout_width="40dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="end"
                                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ad_item_spacing_3"
                                android:paddingRight="@dimen/ad_item_spacing_3"
                                android:src="@drawable/ellipsis"/>
                        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
                    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                    <FlexibleTabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/flexible_tab_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?attr/primaryBackground"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation"
                        android:theme="@style/tabLayoutTheme"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"/>

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```